# How can I do a constructive proof of this:

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions, random-variables

Say Z is a non-negative R.V, and P(Z>0)>0. Then exists a a>0 and an b>0 such P(Z>a)>b. I am not sure how to start with the proof, I've been assigning numbers than can qualify for some CDFs but I don´t know how to prove it for any CDF, who has any ideas?

Comment: Why not try for example $b=P(Z\gt 0)/2$ and then see what happens if there is no $a \gt 0$ with $P(Z\gt a) \gt b$

Comment: Try using lower bound property of probability measure possibly may be useful

Answer (score 1):

Suppose otherwise, that $P(Z>a)=0$ for all $a>0$. If your cdf is continuous, then $$0=\lim_{a \to 0}P(Z>a)=P(Z>0) \ne 0,$$
a contradiction.

Answer (score 0):

$\left\{ Z>0\right\} =\cup_{n=1}^{\infty}\left\{ Z>n^{-1}\right\} $
and consequently $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}P\left\{ Z>n^{-1}\right\} \geq P\left\{ Z>0\right\} >0$.

Then $P\left\{ Z>n^{-1}\right\} >0$ must be true for some $n$.

Taking $b>0$ small enough (e.g. $b=\frac{1}{2}P\left\{ Z>n^{-1}\right\} $) we also have $P\left\{ Z>n^{-1}\right\} >b$.