# Can I know the value of an infinite serie?

Tags: sequences-and-series, exponential-sum

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{n}{e^n}$$

I have found through a software that the value is $\dfrac{e}{(e-1)^2}$.

I've been trying to do it manually but I am getting $\dfrac{\infty}{\infty}$, since I have in the [image]

Comment: By L'Hopital I know it converges, but I don´t know how to get an answer for it

Comment: What happens with your other questions?

Comment: Hi Did, well I had to do it in a different way, by using transformations  for the one you helped me with but I got the same answer yu gave me, I am new in this, would you like me to do something to thank you oficially? press the up arrow?

Comment: If you differentiate the identity (for $\lvert x\rvert < 1$) $$\frac{1}{1-x} = \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n,$$ what do you get?

Comment: @DanielFischer gah.  I promise I wrote my answer before seeing your comment. :\  I'm really bad at the "fastest gun" game...

Comment: Well, for example, [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/940778/), you received two answers and two comments making explicit suggestions, and your reaction to these was... a complete lack of visible reaction. Does this mean that you are still lost, that one answer helped you solve the question, that one comment helped you solve the question, that all of them did, that you are not interested anymore, or still something else? No way to know.

Comment: @anorton Since that is such an esoteric idea, it is of course inconceivable that several people independently had it, right?

Comment: @DanielFischer Of course! :P

Comment: This is a [polylogarithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polylogarithm).

Comment: @Lucian Oh no, not again...

Comment: @Did: I'm just calling a spade a spade. ;-) Or would you rather that I go around, telling people [what things are *not*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Treachery_of_Images) ? :-)

Comment: @Lucian Sure, and the equation of a line in the plane is a holomorphic function... Referring to polylogs in the present context and in some other similar ones where you also did so, is confusing (no need to) and useless (no supplementary wisdom gained).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $f(x)=\sum\limits_{k=0}^\infty x^n=\frac{1}{1-x}$ for $|x|<1$. Differentiating this, we have

$$f'(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty nx^{n-1}=\frac1{(1-x)^2}$$

$$\implies xf'(x)=\sum_{k=0}^\infty nx^{n}=\frac x{(1-x)^2}$$

For $|x|<1$. Since $0<e^{-1}<1$, we can substitute it into the expression to recieve

$${e}^{-1}f'(e^{-1})=\sum_{k=0}^\infty ne^{-n}=\frac {e^{-1}}{(1-e^{-1})^2}=\frac{e}{(e-1)^2}$$

Answer (score 4):

Consider, instead, the series:
$$\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^n &= x\sum_{n=0}^\infty nx^{n-1} \\
&= x\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{d}{dx}x^n \\
&= x\frac{d}{dx}\sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n \\
&= x\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{1}{1-x}\right) \\
&= x\left(\frac{1}{(1-x)^2}\right) \\
&= \frac{x}{(1-x)^2}
\end{align}$$

This converges whenever $|x|< 1$.  By making a smart substitution, you have your result.

Comment: @Peterson If $x=3$, for example, the sum is $0\cdot1+1\cdot3+2\cdot9+3\cdot27+\cdots$, which clearly grows without bound (you can think of, informally, the sum as $\infty$).  But the right hand side evaluated at $3$ is $\frac{3}{4}$, which is certainly finite.

Answer (score 0):

Note $$S_n= \frac{1}{e}+\frac{2}{e^2}+\cdots+\frac{n}{e^n}$$
It is obtained $S_n$ by calculating the difference $$S_n-\frac{1}{e}S_n$$and then get to the limit.